# Keras CNN converging on only one classification

Tags: audio, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been successfully building and  training a standard 4 layer MLP neural network on Keras for an audio classification task. However when I tried to add a convolutional layer to the network, the CNN only successfully trains ~25% of the time. On the other instances, when tested, the network will always predict a single class, giving a 10% accuracy for the 10 class classification problem

I am not sure whether the network is not training at all, whether it is converging on some local minima, or whether it is something different altogether.

My input data are audio signals ~5 seconds in length, which have been converted into a spectrogram and flattened into a vector. There are 10 classes and the MLP model was able to identify the correct class with a ~55% accuracy (not great, but far better than a random guess).

The failed output I am receiving so far looks like this...

```
(5500, 'train samples')
(100, 'test samples')
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 127, 198, 64)  640         convolution2d_input_1[0][0]      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)        (None, 127, 198, 64)  0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 125, 196, 64)  36928       activation_1[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)        (None, 125, 196, 64)  0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 62, 98, 64)    0           activation_2[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 62, 98, 64)    0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 388864)        0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 128)           49774720    flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)        (None, 128)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 128)           0           activation_3[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            1290        dropout_2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 49813578
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Train on 5500 samples, validate on 100 samples
Epoch 1/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 72s - loss: 2.3067 - acc: 0.0929 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 2/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 69s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.0958 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 3/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 69s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.0875 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 4/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 69s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0882 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

...


Epoch 99/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 69s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0865 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
Epoch 100/100
5500/5500 [==============================] - 69s - loss: 2.3027 - acc: 0.0920 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

('Test score:', 2.3025851917266844)
('Test accuracy:', 0.10000000000000001)

 32/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1s
 64/100 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s
 96/100 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
100/100 [==============================] - ETA: 0s     
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

As you can see, the network only ever predicted class 5. In addition to this, the loss never actually reduced.

In contrast, the successful runs looked like this...

```
    (5500, 'train samples')
    (100, 'test samples')

    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
    ====================================================================================================
    convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 126, 197, 64)  1088        convolution2d_input_1[0][0]      
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_1 (Activation)        (None, 126, 197, 64)  0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 123, 194, 64)  65600       activation_1[0][0]               
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_2 (Activation)        (None, 123, 194, 64)  0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 61, 97, 64)    0           activation_2[0][0]               
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 61, 97, 64)    0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 378688)        0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 128)           48472192    flatten_1[0][0]                  
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_3 (Activation)        (None, 128)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 128)           0           activation_3[0][0]               
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            1290        dropout_2[0][0]                  
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    activation_4 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    
    ====================================================================================================
    Total params: 48540170
    ____________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Train on 5500 samples, validate on 100 samples
    Epoch 1/100
    5500/5500 [==============================] - 82s - loss: 2.3210 - acc: 0.0976 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
    Epoch 2/100
    5500/5500 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 2.3034 - acc: 0.0967 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000
    Epoch 3/100
    5500/5500 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 2.2284 - acc: 0.1631 - val_loss: 1.9165 - val_acc: 0.3800

    ...

    Epoch 99/100
    5500/5500 [==============================] - 79s - loss: 0.0169 - acc: 0.9933 - val_loss: 3.7371 - val_acc: 0.5400
    Epoch 100/100
    5500/5500 [==============================] - 79s - loss: 0.0207 - acc: 0.9918 - val_loss: 3.1487 - val_acc: 0.5700

    ('Test score:', 3.1486789989471435)
('Test accuracy:', 0.56999999999999995)

 32/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s
 64/100 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s
 96/100 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
100/100 [==============================] - 0s     
[0 2 5 5 1 9 5 6 9 3 0 7 8 2 6 7 6 4 1 6 2 5 1 7 0 0 0 8 4 5 1 0 4 5 2 9 9
 2 6 0 2 0 4 1 3 0 5 4 4 4 8 7 6 5 9 1 5 7 9 9 2 9 7 1 1 8 5 8 6 4 1 4 9 5
 6 5 4 0 9 4 1 5 6 9 4 4 8 2 9 5 0 0 1 9 4 5 9 5 4 0]

 32/100 [========>.....................] - ETA: 0s
 64/100 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s
 96/100 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s
100/100 [==============================] - 0s     
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Class 0       0.77      1.00      0.87        10
     Class 1       0.91      1.00      0.95        10
     Class 2       0.88      0.70      0.78        10
     Class 3       0.50      0.10      0.17        10
     Class 4       0.20      0.30      0.24        10
     Class 5       0.56      0.90      0.69        10
     Class 6       0.67      0.60      0.63        10
     Class 7       0.33      0.20      0.25        10
     Class 8       0.50      0.30      0.37        10
     Class 9       0.43      0.60      0.50        10

avg / total       0.57      0.57      0.55       100

[[10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  7  0  0  3  0  0  0  0]
 [ 2  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  6]
 [ 0  0  0  1  3  0  1  3  2  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  1]
 [ 1  0  1  0  0  0  6  1  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  6  1  0  2  0  1]
 [ 0  1  0  0  5  0  1  0  3  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  3  1  0  0  6]]
```

Here is the network I have been running

```
import numpy as np
import os, csv, gc, time, random
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nb_classes = 10
batch_size = 32
nb_epoch = 100
img_rows, img_cols = 129, 200
size_of_samples = img_rows * img_cols
samplesDir = './samples'
trainFrom = 'Train'
testFrom = 'Test'


def parallel_shuffle(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    p = np.random.permutation(len(a))
    return a[p], b[p]


def populate_file_arrays():
    train_files = []
    test_files = []
    sample_num = 0
    while len(train_files) < nb_classes and sample_num < 30:
        file_name = os.path.join(samplesDir, trainFrom, "sample" + str(sample_num) + ".txt")
        # print("trying {}".format(file_name))
        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            train_files.append(file_name)
            test_files.append(os.path.join(samplesDir, testFrom, "sample" + str(sample_num) + ".txt"))
            # print("{} worked".format(sample_num))
            sample_num += 1
        else:
            sample_num += 1
    assert(train_files and test_files)
    return train_files, test_files


def sample_handling(sample):
    print("Opening", sample)
    featureset = np.array(list(csv.reader(open(sample, "r"), delimiter=','))).astype('float')
    return featureset


def create_feature_sets_and_labels(train_set, test_set):
    print("Creating featuresets")
    sample_class = 0
    for samples in train_set:

        if sample_class == 0:
            train_x = sample_handling(samples)
            train_y = np.empty(len(train_x), dtype=int)
            train_y.fill(sample_class)
        else:
            new_sample = sample_handling(samples)
            train_x = np.concatenate((train_x, new_sample), axis=0)
            classification = np.empty(len(new_sample), dtype=int)
            classification.fill(sample_class)
            train_y = np.append(train_y, classification)
        sample_class += 1

    sample_class = 0
    for samples in test_set:
        if sample_class == 0:
            test_x = sample_handling(samples)
            test_y = np.empty(len(test_x), dtype=int)
            test_y.fill(sample_class)
        else:
            new_sample = sample_handling(samples)
            test_x = np.concatenate((test_x, new_sample), axis=0)
            classification = np.empty(len(new_sample), dtype=int)
            classification.fill(sample_class)
            test_y = np.append(test_y, classification)
        sample_class += 1

    train_x, train_y = parallel_shuffle(train_x, train_y)
    test_x, test_y = parallel_shuffle(test_x, test_y)

    return (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y)

trainFiles, testFiles = populate_file_arrays()

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = create_feature_sets_and_labels(trainFiles, testFiles)
# (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()



# number of convolutional filters to use
nb_filters = 64
# size of pooling area for max pooling
pool_size = (2, 2)
# convolution kernel size
kernel_size = (4, 4)

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
# (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)


# X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, size_of_samples)
# X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, size_of_samples)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

minVal = np.amin(X_train)
X_train -= minVal
X_test -= minVal
maxVal = np.amax(X_train)
X_train /= maxVal
X_test /= maxVal

print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
print(np.amin(X_train), np.amax(X_train))
print(np.amin(X_test), np.amax(X_test))

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, nb_classes)

print(X_train.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)


############################# MLP model #################################

# model = Sequential()
# model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(size_of_samples,)))
# model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Dense(512))
# model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
# model.add(Activation('softmax'))
#
# # model.summary()
#
# model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#
# history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
# score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
# print('Test score:', score[0])
# print('Test accuracy:', score[1])


#################### Convolutional model ####################

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                        border_mode='valid',
                        input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()

plt.savefig('CNN.png')

y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
print(y_pred)

p = model.predict_proba(X_test)  # to predict probability

target_names = ['sample 0', 'sample 1', 'sample 2', 'sample 3', 'sample 4', 'sample 5', 'sample 6', 'sample 7', 'sample 8', 'sample 9']
print(classification_report(np.argmax(Y_test, axis=1), y_pred, target_names=target_names))
print(confusion_matrix(np.argmax(Y_test, axis=1), y_pred))

gc.collect()
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems that even in your successful attempts, the loss does not decrease. 
Also, did you split your set into training and validation?

Comment: The loss is decreasing (starts at 2.31 and finishes at 0.02).

Comment: Oups, my bad, I did not see the full code.